# php5-fpm stack trace cuts off end of string

Tags: php, nginx, error-log

When a particularly long string gets printed to php5-fpm.log the string gets cut off at the end and "..." is shown (without the quotes) to indicate it's been cut off. How can I make it so it displays the whole string regardless of length?

I'm using Nginx with MySQL, PHP and Laravel if that matters. Basically when I print something to the error log like the following:

```
error_log(print_r($long_str, TRUE));
```

If $long_str is long enough it gets cut off. I'm using this for debugging purposes and this worked fine when I was working in Apache so I think it may have something to do with Nginx.

I've tried changing...

```
log_errors_max_len = 1024
```

to

```
log_errors_max_len = 60000
```

in both /etc/php5/cli/php.ini and /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini

But it doesn't seem to do anything. How can I get the full string to be printed?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/1076

This is a hardcoded limit in php-fpm, the above pull request is trying to remove the limit. The limit was added because syslog, to follow the original RFC. Yet the newer RFC version removed that limit and most people are requesting that the size and message format be configurable in php-fpm